# Get latest value from redux after submit without reloading

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a simple update of name on my application.
I used redux and axios to call the api to update the specific field. However, I'm not getting the latest value of what I have submitted not until I reload the page. I also used Formik for the form.
I also don't want to update the name not until it's submitted.
That's why I used the `details.name` from redux instead the value in useState

How can I get the latest value without reloading the page?

Here's my code

```
{/* {getting the initial value from redux} */}
const [nameValue, setNameValue] = useState(details.name); 

<Formik
  validationSchema={ValidationSchema}
  initialValues={{
    name: details.name,
  }}
  validateOnChange
  validateOnBlur
  onSubmit={values => {
    if (values.name) {
       {/* {This is my action to call the API to update the name} */}
       setTargetGoalName({
        policyId: policyDetails?.policyId,
        name: values.name,
       });
     }
   }}
 >
  {({ errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur, setFieldValue, handleSubmit, setFieldTouched }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
     <InputText
       id="name"
       type="text"
       name="name"
       setFieldValue={setFieldValue}
       placeholder="Enter your name"
       value={nameValue}
       error={touched.name && errors.name ? errors.name : false}
       onBlur={handleBlur}
       onChange={(e) => {
         setNameValue(e.target.value);
         handleChange(e);
         setFieldTouched("name", false);
       }}
     />
    </form>
  )}
</Formik>

// This is where I get the latest value
<p>{details.name}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how to fetch the data of details object in redux
But you should need to invoke the function to refetch the data of detail object

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here the problem lies in how you update your redux state :

> To update a state inside a store is to dispatch an action and define a reducer function to perform tasks based on the given actions. Once dispatched, the action goes inside the reducer functions which performs the tasks and return the updated state to the store. This is what Redux is all about.

Take a look at this basic [example](https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started#basic-example) from docs.

---

> I also used Formik for the form. I also don't want to update the name not until it's submitted

Since in `onChange` you are updating `nameValue` the component will rerender on every input change, this is not what you want.
what you have to do is to make the input `value` property equal to `{formik.values.name}` and get rid of `setNameValue(e.target.value)`

```js
value={formik.values.name}
onChange={(e) => {
  handleChange(e);
  setFieldTouched("name", false);
}}
```